# using a loop for fetching the output but i don't want multiple outputs I need only a single output

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can I get a single output by using loop in pl/sql instead of multiple outputs?

Below is my query and the output I am getting.

```
declare 

    CURSOR VALIGN_DAILY IS
     SELECT AUDT.WKFL_NM,
    AUDT.JOB_STAT,
    AUDT.STRT_DT,
    AUDT.END_DT,
    AUDT.SRC_REC_CNT,
    AUDT.TGT_REC_CNT,
    AUDT.ERR_REC_CNT
    FROM  CRMF_AUDT_PROC_LOG AUDT
   WHERE AUDT.WKFL_NM IN ('wf_ALIGNMENT_TERR_FIELDFORCE_EZFLEX_INB','wf_ALIGNMENT_USER_TERR_EZFLEX_INB','wf_ALIGNMENT_FIELDFORCE_STG_INB','wf_ALIGNMENT_TERR_STG_INB','wf_ALIGNMENT_USER_TERR_STG_INB')
     AND (AUDT.JOB_STAT = 'S' OR AUDT.JOB_STAT = 'P' OR AUDT.JOB_STAT = 'E' OR AUDT.JOB_STAT = 'F')
     AND TRUNC(AUDT.STRT_DT)=TRUNC(SYSDATE);

  VALIGNSTATUS VALIGN_DAILY%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN


FOR VALIGNSTATUS IN VALIGN_DAILY LOOP


CASE VALIGNSTATUS.JOB_STAT
   WHEN 'S' THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALIGN_DAILY' || ' ' || 'COMPLETED' || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.STRT_DT || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.END_DT || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.WKFL_NM);
   WHEN 'P' THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALIGN_DAILY' || ' ' || 'IN_PROGRESS' || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.STRT_DT || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.END_DT || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.WKFL_NM);
   WHEN 'E' THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALIGN_DAILY' || ' ' || 'ERRED' || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.STRT_DT || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.END_DT || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.WKFL_NM);
   WHEN 'F' THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALIGN_DAILY' || ' ' || 'FAILED' || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.STRT_DT || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.END_DT || ' ' || VALIGNSTATUS.WKFL_NM);
  ELSE
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('VALIGN_DAILY' || ' ' || 'NOT_STARTED' || ' ' || 'N/A' || ' ' || 'N/A');
  END CASE;

END LOOP;
end;
```

And my output is like--

```
VALIGN_DAILY COMPLETED 28-MAY-2018 28-MAY-2018 wf_ALIGNMENT_FIELDFORCE_STG_INB
VALIGN_DAILY COMPLETED 28-MAY-2018 28-MAY-2018 wf_ALIGNMENT_USER_TERR_EZFLEX_INB
VALIGN_DAILY COMPLETED 28-MAY-2018 28-MAY-2018 wf_ALIGNMENT_TERR_FIELDFORCE_EZFLEX_INB
VALIGN_DAILY COMPLETED 28-MAY-2018 28-MAY-2018 wf_ALIGNMENT_USER_TERR_STG_INB
VALIGN_DAILY COMPLETED 28-MAY-2018 28-MAY-2018 wf_ALIGNMENT_TERR_STG_INB
```

Comment: your question is not clear,please correct it and post again.

Comment: If you want to get a help you need to have at last your code formatted. So leave the formatting on. See [ask]

Comment: dbms_output.put

Comment: It is not clear what output you want to see. We cannot guess it based on your  line "I need only a single output". You have multiple rows in the table for each condition and it is displaying multiple times. I would suggest you to edit your question and show some sample rows and the expected output. Only in text format, **no** images please.

Comment: There's a loop, and it displays *something* for every iteration (because of ELSE; if everything fails, ELSE won't), so I - as well as previous commentators - have no idea what a "single output" means to you..